# Why accented letters are not interpreted correctly in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following problem in express, I get a string in a post request containing the following characters
'a e i o u', the string is interpreted correctly, but adding a percent sign ('% á é í ó ú') letters with accent become question marks ('�'), any ideas?

This is my -package.json-: https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/f05fd6de3b2b218e6d17

This is where the -index.js- receipt request: https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/ae6533e14078bc9b0119

iojs v2.2.1[image]

Comment: My guess is that the uploaded string isn't actually utf-8 encoded.

Comment: It could be, but because without the character '%' if it works?

Comment: It's not clear to me if the client you're using is smart enough to quote the `%` (which has special meaning in url-encoded data) or if it will pass the data to the server as-is and the server gets confused by it.

Comment: it's confusing but create a sample project, check this https://github.com/ripper2hl/error-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample project, you tell `body-parser` not to use the extended query string parser ([here](https://github.com/ripper2hl/error-encoding/blob/master/server/config/express.js#L16)).

This will make it use the built-in [`querystring`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module for parsing query strings, which is less robust than the one used as the extended parser ([`qs`](https://github.com/hapijs/qs)).

You can see the differences between these two parsers with this PoC:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var qs          = require('qs');
var input       = 'data=% á é í ó ú';

console.log('querystring:', querystring.parse(input) );
console.log('qs         :', qs.parse(input) );
```

The output reproduces what you're seeing:

```
querystring: { data: '% � � � � �' }
qs         : { data: '% á é í ó ú' }
```

Ultimately, it boils down to your input, which is invalid in terms of URL-encoding:

- `%` has special meaning (as an escape character)
- spaces should be encoded
- non-ASCII characters should be encoded

The valid input data looks like this:

```
data=%25%20%C3%A1%20%C3%A9%20%C3%AD%20%C3%B3%20%C3%BA
```